# How to return the index of a for loop in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let find_free_next heap start = 
  for i = start to ((Array.length heap)-1) do
     match heap.(i) with 
     Hdr (Free (h), g)  ->
        i
  done
```

How can i return the index of a loop as an integer once the match has been found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to stick to the imperative style, you can use an exception to exit the loop:

---

```
exception Found of int

let find_free_next heap start = 
  try
    for i = start to Array.length heap - 1 do
       match heap.(i) with 
       | Hdr (Free (h), g)  -> raise (Found i)
       | _ -> () (* If it is not what you are seeking *)
    done;
    raise Not_found   
  with
  | Found n -> n
```

---

But generally, as ppl have already written, functional style is more preferred in OCaml:

---

```
let find_free_next heap start =
  let len = Array.length heap in
  let rec find i =
    if i >= len then None
    else 
      match heap.(i) with
      | Hdr (Free h, g) -> Some i
      | _ -> find (i+1)
  in
  find start
```

---

In this example, there is not much difference between the two versions, but use of exceptions for exiting loops/recursions must be used with caution; you can introduce control flow bugs pretty easily with them, and they are sometimes hard to debug.

BTW, you can use Array.unsafe_get heap i to speed up your array access since you can be sure that i is always in the valid range of the array the above examples. (Oh, we need start >= 0 check in addition, though.)

Answer (score 5):

Asumu Takikawa is right, the `for` loop in OCaml doesn't return a result.  In idiomatic OCaml, you should use recursion instead.  Ideally there would be a standard function like `List.find` that works for arrays.  There is a function [`BatArray.findi`](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatArray.html) in [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) that does what you seem to want.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler, and more efficient (no allocation at all):

```
let rec find_free_next heap start =
  if start = Array.length heap then raise Not_found;
  match heap.(i) with
  | Hdr (Free h, g) -> i
  | _ -> find_free_start heap (i+1)
```

Or, in imperative style:

```
let exit = Exit
let find_free_next heap start =
  let pos = ref (-1) in
  try
    for i = start to Array.length heap - 1 do
      match heap.(i) with
      | Hdr (Free h, g) -> pos := i; raise exit
      | _ -> ()
    done;
    raise Not_found
  with Exit -> !pos
```

(notice that `raise exit` does not allocate only because the exception if precomputed).

Comment: By "the exception is precomputed", do you mean that adding the `let exit = Exit` before the loop is what prevents some inefficiencies here? Would this still be the case with a recent OCaml compiler?

Answer (score 4):

Loops in Ocaml are supposed to be imperative, so it shouldn't return a result (aside from unit). So if you try to return a non-unit result, the compiler will give a warning.

The reason that Ocaml doesn't let you return a result from a loop is because this isn't a very functional idiom. If you use a recursive function instead of a loop, it's easy to exit early and return a result (by returning the result instead of recurring). If you want to write idiomatic Ocaml, you probably want to use recursion in this case.