# Idiomatic exceptions for exiting loops in OCaml

Tags: loops, ocaml, idioms, imperative-programming

In OCaml, imperative-style loops can be exited early by raising exceptions.

While the use of imperative loops is not idiomatic *per se* in OCaml, I'd like to know what are the most idiomatic ways to emulate imperative loops with early exits (taking into account aspects such as performance, if possible).

For instance, [an old OCaml FAQ](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/controle_de_base-eng.html#break) mentions exception `Exit`:

> `Exit`: used to jump out of loops or functions.

Is it still current? The [standard library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) simply mentions it as a general-purpose exception:

> The `Exit` exception is not raised by any library function. It is provided for use in your programs.

Relatedly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9465528/1173674) to another question mentions using a precomputed `let exit = Exit` exception to avoid allocations inside the loop. Is it still required?

Also, sometimes one wants to exit from the loop with a specific value, such as `raise (Leave 42)`. Is there an idiomatic exception or naming convention to do this? Should I use references in this case (e.g. `let res = ref -1 in ... <loop body> ... res := 42; raise Exit`)?

Finally, the use of `Exit` in nested loops prevents some cases where one would like to exit several loops, like `break <label>` in Java. This would require defining exceptions with different names, or at least using an integer to indicate how many scopes should be exited (e.g. `Leave 2` to indicate that 2 levels should be exited). Again, is there an approach/exception naming that is idiomatic here?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but whatever you end up doing, since OCaml 4.02, you should use `raise_notrace` for control-flow exceptions to ensure that a backtrace is not created even if debugging is turned on: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html. For your reference, I use continuations to solve most of the problems you are describing.

Comment: Just to be clear, an "idiomatic" way to get the effects of early exit like Java labels is to create failure continuations that will cause "return" to parts of your program. You then pass the failure continuations, and other code can call them with a value to "exit" immediately to any of those points. It's much more general than exit from loops, since you can "exit" from anything that gets one of these continuations. It's also type-safe, since you have to pass the continuation the type of value expected by the context at the exit point. I'm not sure it's what you're looking for, however.

Comment: @antron i almost understand what you mean. could you possibly make a minimal example with code as an answer? i would upvote ;)

Comment: Yes, give me a bit to dredge up my code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As originally posted in comments, the idiomatic way to do early exit in OCaml is using continuations. At the point where you want the early return to go to, you create a continuation, and pass it to the code that might return early. This is more general than labels for loops, since you can exit from just about anything that has access to the continuation.

Also, as posted in comments, note the usage of `raise_notrace` for exceptions whose trace you never want the runtime to generate.

A "naive" first attempt:

```
module Continuation :
sig
  (* This is the flaw with this approach: there is no good choice for
     the result type. *)
  type 'a cont = 'a -> unit

  (* with_early_exit f passes a function "k" to f. If f calls k,
     execution resumes as if with_early_exit completed
     immediately. *)
  val with_early_exit : ('a cont -> 'a) -> 'a
end =

struct
  type 'a cont = 'a -> unit

  (* Early return is implemented by throwing an exception. The ref
     cell is used to store the value with which the continuation is
     called - this is a way to avoid having to generate an exception
     type that can store 'a for each 'a this module is used with. The
     integer is supposed to be a unique identifier for distinguishing
     returns to different nested contexts. *)
  type 'a context = 'a option ref * int64
  exception Unwind of int64

  let make_cont ((cell, id) : 'a context) =
    fun result -> cell := Some result; raise_notrace (Unwind id)

  let generate_id =
    let last_id = ref 0L in
    fun () -> last_id := Int64.add !last_id 1L; !last_id

  let with_early_exit f =
    let id = generate_id () in
    let cell = ref None in
    let cont : 'a cont = make_cont (cell, id) in
    try
      f cont
    with Unwind i when i = id ->
      match !cell with
      | Some result -> result
        (* This should never happen... *)
      | None        -> failwith "with_early_exit"
end



let _ =
  let nested_function i k = k 15; i in

  Continuation.with_early_exit (nested_function 42)
  |> string_of_int
  |> print_endline
```

As you can see, the above implements early exit by hiding an exception. The continuation is actually a partially applied function that knows the unique id of the context for which it was created, and has a reference cell to store the result value while the exception is being thrown to that context. The code above prints 15. You can pass the continuation `k` as deep as you want. You can also define the function `f` immediately at the point where it is passed to `with_early_exit`, giving an effect similar to having a label on a loop. I use this very often.

The problem with the above is the result type of `'a cont`, which I arbitrarily set to `unit`. Actually, a function of type `'a cont` never returns, so we want it to behave like `raise` – be usable where any type is expected. However, this doesn't immediately work. If you do something like `type ('a, 'b) cont = 'a -> 'b`, and pass that down to your nested function, the type checker will infer a type for `'b` in one context, and then force you to call continuations only in contexts with the same type, i.e. you won't be able to do things like

```
(if ... then 3 else k 15)
...
(if ... then "s" else k 16)
```

because the first expression forces `'b` to be `int`, but the second requires `'b` to be `string`.

To solve this, we need to provide a function analogous to `raise` for early return, i.e.

```
(if ... then 3 else throw k 15)
...
(if ... then "s" else throw k 16)
```

This means stepping away from pure continuations. We have to un-partially-apply `make_cont` above (and I renamed it to `throw`), and pass the naked context around instead:

```
module BetterContinuation :
sig
  type 'a context

  val throw : 'a context -> 'a -> _
  val with_early_exit : ('a context -> 'a) -> 'a
end =

struct
  type 'a context = 'a option ref * int64
  exception Unwind of int64

  let throw ((cell, id) : 'a context) =
    fun result -> cell := Some result; raise_notrace (Unwind id)

  let generate_id = (* Same *)

  let with_early_exit f =
    let id = generate_id () in
    let cell = ref None in
    let context = (cell, id) in
    try
      f context
    with Unwind i when i = id ->
      match !cell with
      | Some result -> result
      | None        -> failwith "with_early_exit"
end



let _ =
  let nested_function i k = ignore (BetterContinuation.throw k 15); i in

  BetterContinuation.with_early_exit (nested_function 42)
  |> string_of_int
  |> print_endline
```

The expression `throw k v` can be used in contexts where different types are required.

I use this approach pervasively in some big applications I work on. I prefer it even to regular exceptions. I have a more elaborate variant, where `with_early_exit` has a signature roughly like this:

```
val with_early_exit : ('a context -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b
```

where the first function represents an attempt to do something, and the second represents the handler for errors of type `'a` that may result. Together with variants and polymorphic variants, this gives a more explicitly-typed take on exception handling. It is especially powerful with polymorphic variants, as the set of error variands can be inferred by the compiler.

The Jane Street approach effectively does the same as what is described here, and in fact I previously had an implementation that generated exception types with first-class modules. I am not sure anymore why I eventually chose this one – there may be subtle differences :)

Comment: By the way, both the need to pass naked contexts above, and the usage of a record by Jane Street are due to a flaw in the OCaml type system, namely the lack of a "bottom" type. The goal of both "BetterContinuation" and the Jane Street record is to provide functions that can have fresh result types inferred in each context they are used.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer a specific part of my question which was not mentioned in other answers:

> ... using a precomputed let exit = Exit exception to avoid allocations inside the loop. Is it still required?

I did some micro-benchmarks using `Core_bench` on `4.02.1+fp` and the results indicate no significant difference: when comparing two identical loops, one containing a local `exit` declared before the loop and another one without it, the time difference is minimal.

The difference between `raise Exit` and `raise_notrace Exit` in this example was also minimal, about 2% in some runs, up to 7% in others, but it could well be within the error margins of such a short experiment.

Overall, I couldn't measure any noticeable difference, so unless someone would have examples where `Exit/exit` significantly affect performance, I would prefer the former since it is clearer and avoids creating a mostly useless variable.

Finally, I also compared the difference between two idioms: using a reference to a value before exiting the loop, or creating a specific exception type containing the return value.

With reference to result value + `Exit`:

```
 let res = ref 0 in
 let r =
   try
     for i = 0 to n-1 do
       if a.(i) = v then
        (res := v; raise_notrace Exit)
     done;
     assert false
   with Exit -> !res
 in ...
```

With specific exception type:

```
 exception Res of int
 let r =
   try
     for i = 0 to n-1 do
       if a.(i) = v then
         raise_notrace (Res v)
     done;
     assert false
   with Res v -> v
 in ...
```

Once again, the differences were minimal and varied a lot between runs. Overall, the first version (reference + `Exit`) seemed to have a slight advantage (0% to 10% faster), but the difference was not significant enough to recommend one version over the another.

Since the former requires defining an initial value (which may not exist) or using an option type to initialize the reference, and the latter requires defining a new exception per type of value returned from the loop, there is no ideal solution here.

Answer (score 1):

`Exit` is ok (I'm not sure whether I can say that it is idiomatic). But, make sure, that you're using `raise_notrace`, if you're using recent enough compiler (since 4.02).

Even better solution, is to use `with_return` from [OCaml Core library](https://github.com/janestreet/core). It will not have any problems with scope, because it will create a fresh new exception type for each nesting.

Of course, you can achieve the same results, or just take the source code of Core's implementation.

And even more idiomatic, is not to use exceptions for short-circuiting your iteration, and consider to use existing algorithm (`find`, `find_map`, `exists`, etc) or just write a recursive function, if no algorithm suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the point

> using a precomputed let exit = Exit exception to avoid allocations
>   inside the loop. Is it still required?

the answer is *no* with sufficiently recent versions of OCaml. Here is the relevant excerpt from the Changelog of OCaml 4.02.0.

> - PR#6203: Constant exception constructors no longer allocate   (Alain Frisch)

Here is PR6203: http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6203